# How to resample an image in java maintaining it physical size?

Tags: java, imagemagick

Let's say I have an image 144x144 px with a ppi(pixels per inch) of 144. So my image is physically a 1x1 inch square. Now I want to reduce its pixel density to 72 ppi but still retain its physical dimensions of 1x1 inch square. To make this happen, it would be necessary to now have the image as 72x72 px in terms of pixels. I want to achieve this with only these inputs available:

- The Image
- The target ppi

This is very similar to what is done in [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resample) as follows

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch original_144by144.jpg -resample resampled_72 72by72.jpg
```

The ImageMagick command above internally takes of retaining the image's physical dimensions when doing the resampling.

I want to do this in Java. Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I just want people to realize that **Pixels Per Inch** (PPI) is not the same as **Dots Per Inch** (DPI). Even though the terms are often used in reference to the same thing, they are different [Read here for more insight](https://99designs.ca/blog/tips/ppi-vs-dpi-whats-the-difference/).

I personally would just use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) (which is free and [open source](https://github.com/ImageMagick)) through the Java application since ImageMagick works quite well as a Command-Line application, for example:

```
String imageMagickLocation = "D:\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\magick.exe";
String sourceImagePath = "C:\\Users\\DevilsHnd\\Pictures\\MyImage.png";
String destinationPath = "C:\\Users\\DevilsHnd\\Pictures\\New_MyImage.png"; 
int desiredPPI = 72;
String commandLineString = imageMagickLocation + " convert -units PixelsPerInch \"" 
                         + sourceImagePath + "\" -resample " + desiredPPI + " \"" 
                         + destinationPath + "\""; 

List<String> list = runCMD(commandLineString);

/* Display any results from the call to the runCMD() 
   method. If ImageMagick is successful then there 
   should be nothing (the List should be empty).  */
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

The **runCMD()** method provided below allows your application to run Command Line applications as you would through the Windows 'Command Prompt' window:

```
/**
 * This method is specifically designed for running the Microsoft Windows CMD 
 * command prompt and having the results that would normally be displayed within 
 * a Command Prompt Window placed into a string List Interface instead.<br><br>
 * <p>
 * <b>Example Usage:</b><pre>
 *       {@code 
 *          List<String> list = runCMD("/C dir");
 *          for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
 *              System.out.println(list.get(i));
 *          }
 *       } </pre>
 *
 * @param commandString (String) The command string to pass to the Command
 *                      Prompt. You do not need to place "cmd" within your
 *                      command string because it is applied automatically.
 *                      As a matter of fact if you do it is automatically
 *                      removed.<br> 
 *
 * @return (List&lt;String&gt;) A string List containing the results of
 *         the processed command.
 */
public List<String> runCMD(String commandString) {
    if (commandString.toLowerCase().startsWith("cmd ")) {
        commandString = commandString.substring(4);
    }
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C " + commandString);
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result.add(line);
            }
        }
        p.destroy(); // Kill the process
        return result;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>IO Error during processing of runCMD()!"
                                    + "<br><br>" + e.getMessage() + "</html>",
                                      "runCMD() Method Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return null;
    }
}
```

To convert an image to 72 Pixels Per Inch (PPI) with ImageMagick works relatively fast however setting a PPI higher than the original source PPI could take somewhat longer depending upon the difference. Whatever you do, don't do something crazy like convert an image to 2000 PPI unless you have a Super-Computer with a vast amount of memory (ImageMagick will attempt to do it). As a matter of fact, you would want to install safeguards to prevent conversions of unreasonable PPI values.

A typical command line operation of ImageMagick to resample an specific image to say 72 PPI would be:

```
D:\ImagMagick\magick.exe convert -units PixelsPerInch "C:\Pictures\MyImageName1.png" -resample 72 "C:\Pictures\MyImageName2.png"

                            O R

D:\ImagMagick\magick.exe convert -units PixelsPerInch "C:\Pictures\MyImageName1.png" -resample 72 "C:\Pictures\MyImageName2.jpg"
```

**Notice** the destination file name extension change between the two conversion calls. The source and destination file paths and or file names are enclosed within quotation marks just in case one or more whitespaces are contained within them.

Also, you can easily modify things to carry out batch Image file conversions. I believe ImageMagick has batch capabilities through the command-line as well.

Comment: Thanks DevilsHnd. Though I was looking for a pure java solution because of reasons beyond my control :)